# Keycloak Server Admin Console Blocked Mixed Content Response on AWS K3S Kubernetes Cluster with Istio Gateway and AWS HTTPS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, keycloak, istio, istio-gateway

I was able to successfully start **keycloak server** on **AWS K3S Kubernetes Cluster** with **Istio Gateway** and **AWS HTTPS Application Load Balancer**.

I can successfully see **Keycloak Home Page**:
**https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/auth/**

But when I click on **Admin Console** link, then the **Blank Page** is shown:
**https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/auth/admin/master/console/**

**Browser Inspect Tool** shows that:
**http://keycloak.skycomposer.net/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=rk826**
link returns the following status:

```
(blocked:mixed-content)
```

I did some research on the internet and the reason seems to be related with redirection from **https** to **http**, which is not correctly handled by **istio gateway** and **aws load balancer**

But unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution, how to solve it for my particular environment.

Here are my configuration files:

**keycloak-config.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: keycloak
data:
  KEYCLOAK_USER: admin@keycloak
  KEYCLOAK_MGMT_USER: mgmt@keycloak
  JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: '-Djboss.http.port=8080'
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
  KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: 'keycloak.skycomposer.net'
  KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: 'https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/auth'  
  KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO
  ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
  DB_VENDOR: H2
```

**keycloak-deployment.yaml:**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              hostPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-data
              mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_USER
            - name: KEYCLOAK_MGMT_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_MGMT_USER
            - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: DB_VENDOR
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
            - name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
            - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
            - name: ROOT_LOGLEVEL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: ROOT_LOGLEVEL
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
            - name: KEYCLOAK_MGMT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak
                  key: KEYCLOAK_MGMT_PASSWORD
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: keycloak-pvc
```

**keycloak-service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
```

**istio-gateway.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-gateway
spec: 
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "keycloak.skycomposer.net"
```

**istio-virtualservice.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  hosts:
    - keycloak.skycomposer.net
  gateways:
    - istio-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: keycloak.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
```

I successfully installed **istio 1.9.1** with **istioctl**:

```
istioctl install \
  --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout \
  --skip-confirmation
```

Also, I labelled default namespace with **istio injection**, so all my pods in default namespace have **istio sidecar container**:

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled

NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
whoami-6c4757bbb5-9zkbl                      2/2     Running   0          13m
notification-microservice-5dfcf96b95-ll8lm   2/2     Running   0          13m
customermgmt-6b48586868-ddlnw                2/2     Running   0          13m
usermgmt-c5b65964-df2vc                      2/2     Running   0          13m
keycloak-d48f9bbbf-tsm5h                     2/2     Running   0          13m
```

Here is also **terraform** configuration of **AWS Load Balancer**:

```
resource "aws_lb" "mtc_lb" {
  name            = "mtc-loadbalancer"
  subnets         = var.public_subnets
  security_groups = [var.public_sg]
  idle_timeout    = 400
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "mtc_tg" {
  name     = "mtc-lb-tg-${substr(uuid(), 0, 3)}"
  port     = var.tg_port
  protocol = var.tg_protocol
  vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = [name]
  }
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = var.elb_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.elb_unhealthy_threshold
    timeout             = var.elb_timeout
    interval            = var.elb_interval
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "mtc_lb_listener_http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.mtc_lb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "mtc_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.mtc_lb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  depends_on        = [aws_lb_target_group.mtc_tg]
  certificate_arn   = var.certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mtc_tg.arn
  }
}
```

Comment: I faced the same with Keycloak 15.0.6
Got it resolved by adding **proxy-address-forwarding="true"** to default http-listener in standalone-ha.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigating **request headers**, I finally found the cause of the issue.

This header was always "**http**" by default:

```
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

Changing the value to:

```
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

solved the issue.

Here is the example of **Istio Virtual Service**, which sets "**X-Forwarded-Proto**" request header to "**https**" for all requests:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  hosts:
    - keycloak.skycomposer.net
  gateways:
    - istio-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: keycloak.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
          headers:
            request:
              set:
                x-forwarded-proto: https
```

P.S. Ideal solution would be to set this value in **AWS Application Load Balancer**, but I wasn't sure how to do it with my **terraform configuration** of **aws load balancer**, so I decided to solve it on **Istio Virtual Service** level.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the virtualservice change you proposed above did not help. Have you looked into this any further?